# Determine if all checkboxes within jQuery object are checked, return as boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, boolean

Hey all. I've been been trying to figure this out for a while now.

I create a jQuery object of checkboxes and store it in a variable:

```
$group1 = $('#checkbox1,#checkbox2,#checkbox3,#checkbox4');
```

The user cannot continue unless all checkboxes in that group are checked.

I've been using an if statement combined with `.is(':checked')` to find a boolean value:

```
if( $group1.is(':checked') ){
  //continue is OK
}
```

...but `.is(':checked')` will return `TRUE` if *any* checkboxes are checked within the group. Essentially, `.is(':checked')` performs an OR operation on the selected elements in $group1. I'm looking for an AND operation, so all selected elements must be checked to return `TRUE`. Is there a jQuery function that does this, or another workaround?

Comment: I suggest that you take the `$` out of your variable names. This is not required in JavaScript and it is intended to be used by mechanically generated code. You _can_ use it (like jQuery does), but it is not good practice to break this convention.

Comment: I would suggest adding classes to your checkboxes so you can do $('.className:checkbox') or, if you want to select all the checkboxes, just do: $(':checkbox')

Comment: @elusive that's actually a very common jQuery convention to represent variables that are jQuery collections.  I recommend he continue using it.  It helps code readability and doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@Adam is off just a bit

```
if( $group1.filter(':not(:checked)').length === 0){
  //continue is OK
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution!

Comment: This is a great solution, works perfectly. Thanks BBonifield and Adam, and everyone else!

Comment: Nice! Clean and simple.

Answer (score 2):

*Corrected:*

You could [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get only the elements that are **[not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) [checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**, and then check to see if any are any elements still in the collection, if there are not than all the elements in the group are checked:

```
if( $group1.filter(':not(:checked)').length === 0){
  //continue is OK
}
```

Comment: If all the checkboxes have to be checked, then `$group1.length == $group.filter(':checked').length` might be more appropriate

Comment: Doesn't solve his problem...he's not looking to see if ANY are checked - he's looking to see if ALL are checked. (Although, it's an easy fix.)

Comment: The logic here would ensure that at least one of the checkboxes is checked rather than ensuring that all of them are.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you give your checkboxes a a class then

```
 var len = $('.check_needed').length;
 var chk = $('.check_needed:checked').length;
 if (len == check){
    //carry on
 }else{
    // go home
 }
```

Comment: adam's solution is basiclly the same EDIT: well BBonified's is

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var checked = true;

   $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
      if(checked){
         checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      }
   });
});
```

This should set checked = false if any of them are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also

$(function(){

```
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selec_all_chk").click(function () {
      $('.chk_class').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// else uncheck
$(".chk_class").click(function(){

    if($(".chk_class").length == $(".chk_class:checked").length) {
        $("#selec_all_chk").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selec_all_chk").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
```

});